# Regex that starts with a pattern and does not end with another pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas, series

Let's say I have this toy `pandas.Series`

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['GarageQual', 'GarageArea', 'GarageCars', 'GarageTestCars', 'GaraFail'])
# 0        GarageQual
# 1        GarageArea
# 2        GarageCars
# 3    GarageTestCars
# 4        GaraFailed
# dtype: object
```

I would like to select all the rows whose value starts with the pattern `'Garage'` **and** does *not* end with the pattern `'Cars'`; hence my desired result would be

```
# 0        GarageQual
# 1        GarageArea
```

Note: I would like to reach it with a regex match.

---

I've tried several attempts but to no avail

```
s.loc[s.str.match('^Garage.*[^Cars]$')]
# 0    GarageQual
# dtype: object

s.loc[s.str.match('^Garage.*^(Cars)$')]
# Series([], dtype: object)

s.loc[s.str.match('^Garage.*^(?!Cars)$')]
# Series([], dtype: object)
```

I feel like I'm very close to the solution, yet I didn't manage to reach my desired result.

Comment: `'^Garage(?!.*Cars$)'`

Comment: I don't understand why I got two downvotes. Apart from being a duplicate (even if when I searched online "python regex starts with pattern and does not end with another" the linked question didn't show up), I think my question is well-posed and contains a small, reproducible example. Is this just meanness or could I have done better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use following regex:
`^Garage.*(?:[^C].{3}|C[^a].{2}|Ca[^r].{1}|Car[^s])$`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/I1UELX/1)

Also `^Garage(?!.*Cars$)` will work in case that you're using library with back-tracking support

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gMdhuI/1)

Comment: The second solution is what I was looking for, thanks! :) What does `?!` exactly do? And why should `.*` be inserted inside the grouping brackets instead of outside?

Comment: `?!` is [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It is used when you want to match something which is not followed by something else. If `.*` inserted outside of bracket, it will match until the end of string (because it's greedy) and then checks if there is `Cars` after that pattern which there isn't, because it already matched until the end of the string! we actually want to say that `.*Cars$` pattern is not after `Garage`. @RicS